# ./configure: No such file or directory when installing Xdebug on OSX

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

As the title shows I'm trying to install Xdebug on OSX (10.13.2)

I followed all the steps on https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and had first problems when it came to running phpize.

Finally I found out which path to use:

```
/usr/local/php5-7.1.1-20170213-100732/bin/phpize
```

that gave me the following output:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
```

So far, so good. But when it comes to the next step where I am supposed to run configure I simply get

> ./configure: No such file or directory

I have no experience in using the terminal and to be honest I don't understand half of what I'm doing. Still I would love to have Xdebug on my local PHP installation. Can anyone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** before someone asks: Yes, I'm running the `./configure` command in the correct directory (xdebug-2.6.0beta1). When I `ls` or just open the folder in Finder it also shows me that there is no such configure file.
It seems that this file has to be created somehow, I just don't know when and how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is:

> autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4

It looks like you need to install GNU m4 with brew:

`brew install m4`

That way, you should get a newer m4.

Alternatively, you might have to (re)install the "Command Line Tools" from within Xcode. ⌘, opens preferences and the install button for the "Command Line Tools" can be found in the "Downloads."